# make angular-ui append modal inside div with class .enable-twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have a big site with lot's of legacy .css with rule names that collides with the ones of twitter bootstrap. As a solution we use a .sass version of bootstrap and have wrapped everything like so:

```
.bootstrap-enabled {

// Grid system and page structure
@import "vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/scaffolding";
@import "vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/grid";
...
```

So if you want to you bootstrap you have to wrap your html in e.g. a `<div class="bootstrap-enabled">`-tag.

This works fine except for [modals in angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) since they are appended to the `body`. And we can't slap a `.bootstrap-enabled` class on the body since then the whole site would be "bootstrap-enabled".

Does anybody know if it's possible to make angular-ui modals append to a specific element in the DOM? Or is there maybe another intelligent solution to this problem?

Comment: Facing same issue, see this issue was closed as not solvable on the Angular UI GitHub (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/896).

Comment: @user645715 sorry, I forgot to post my solution. Just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting the modal and popover outside of the namespace like so:

```
.bootstrap-enabled {
 ...
}

@import "vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/modals";
@import "vendor/bootstrap-sass/lib/tooltip";
```

And then modified the `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js` by adding the `bootstrap-enabled` attributes to the parent elements manually like so:

```
angular.module("template/modal/backdrop.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/backdrop.html",
    "<div class=\"tbs-modal-backdrop bootstrap-enabled fade\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1040 + index*10}\" ng-click=\"close($event)\"></div>");
}]);

angular.module("template/modal/window.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/window.html",
    "<div class=\"tbs-modal bootstrap-enabled fade {{ windowClass }}\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1050 + index*10}\" ng-transclude></div>");
}]);
```